# How to add eval value to onclick js function argument in asp datalist (Front-Side)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to add javascript function to my checkbox which included in a datalist which will take ID of the control as parameter.

I want to do this on the asp page **NOT** at the OnItemDataBound method.
I tried this one but not working. Any ideas?

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID='chkDatabase' runat="server"  CssClass="NormalBold" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' onclick='javascript:showme("<%# Eval("ID") %>")' ></asp:CheckBox>
```

Part of  datalist code:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="ddlDatabases" CssClass="ddlDatabases" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" RepeatLayout="Table" OnItemDataBound="ddlcount_ItemDataBound">                       <ItemTemplate>
<div style=" float: left; width:150px;padding:20px; " >
<asp:CheckBox ID='chkDatabase' runat="server "  CssClass="NormalBold " Text='<%# Eval("Name ") %>' onclick='javascript:showme("<%# Eval("ID") %>")' >
</asp:CheckBox>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried also onclick='<%# "showme(" + Eval("ID") %> + ")"'> ...not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use + operator inside <%# ...%> like this:

```
onclick='<%# showme(" + Eval("ID") + ")"%>'>
```

There is no need to use javascript.

Comment: Awesome ! You saved my day! It totally works! .I used it like that onclick='<%# "changeRolesState(" + Eval("ID") + ");return false;"%>' .Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You cann't Pass parameters in JavaScript as You Show

Remove this from markup

```
onclick='javascript:showme("<%# Eval("ID") %>")'
```

For DataLost add in `DataList_OnItemDataBound` event

```
   OnItemDataBound="DataList1_OnItemDataBound"
```

Code Behind:

```
  protected void DataList1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
      {
         DataListItem row = e.Item;

        CheckBox chkDatabase = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkDatabase");

        chkDatabase.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showme('" + ID + "')");
      }
```

Comment: No think is inside a datalist.i want to do this in the aspx page.

Comment: Nice try but look i want for some reason to do this only in the control's code at front not codebehind

Comment: @Csdtesting You need to find control inside Container Now you can try

Comment: Maybe it works but i want it front side .there should be a way :) .Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: @Csdtesting if you do like that it will just display as 'Eval("ID")' as string not actual values

Comment: There will be something like that showme("6"); at onclick.

Comment: @Csdtesting Yes there is only ways you need to pass through `OnItemDataBound' or Your need to use Javascipt Loop through each checkboxes, get values from variable in javascript and pass those values to function which looks like ugly and lengthy

Comment: I think you are not right because  Text='<%# Eval("Name ") %>' is working fine .Iwant the same for onclick.Let's try

Comment: Beacuse In this ` Text='<%# Eval("Name ") %>'` Your are setting Text not passing Parameters to any function in js

Answer (score 0):

works super

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdAdvTravel">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:EditAdvanceTravelFee( '<%#Eval("fee_catg_srno")%>','<%#Eval("trvl_amt")%>','<%#Eval("pay_date")%>','<%#Eval("fee_name")%>','<%#Eval("status")%>' )" class="btn btn-primary">EDIT</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```